# Are strings referenced in PHP5?

Tags: php, string, reference-counting

Are strings referenced or copied, when passed as arguments or assigned to variables, in PHP5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [**`debug_zval_dump()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-zval-dump.php) function might help you answer this question.

For example, if I run the following portion of code :

```
$str = 'test';
debug_zval_dump($str);      // string(4) "test" refcount(2)

my_function($str);
debug_zval_dump($str);      // string(4) "test" refcount(2)

function my_function($a) {
    debug_zval_dump($a);    // string(4) "test" refcount(4)
    $plop = $a . 'glop';
    debug_zval_dump($a);    // string(4) "test" refcount(4)
    $a = 'boom';
    debug_zval_dump($a);    // string(4) "boom" refcount(2)
}
```

I get the following output :

```
string(4) "test" refcount(2)
string(4) "test" refcount(4)
string(4) "test" refcount(4)
string(4) "boom" refcount(2)
string(4) "test" refcount(2)
```

So, I would say :

- Strings are "refcounted", when passed to functions *(and, probably, when assigned to variables)*
- BUT do not forget that PHP does **copy on write**

For more informations, here are a couple of links that might be useful :

- [Reference Counting Basics](https://www.php.net/features.gc.refcounting-basics)
- [Do not use PHP references](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html)
- [Maitrise de la gestion des variables en PHP](http://julien-pauli.developpez.com/tutoriels/php/variables/?page=page_2) *(in french)*

Comment: I always knew my knowledge of French would come in handy some time.

Comment: I know there are some people arround here who understand french, so I though *"why not post it ?"* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

They are copies or dereferenced.